# Use AWS with Docker: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot application that uses the AWS SQS and S3 service for the business requirements which works fine locally. We have defined the AmazonS3 bean as follow, for authentication it uses the *config* and *credentials* file from the *.aws* folder which gets created using the `aws configure` command and we are not keeping the access key and secret key in the application properties file. I have created the docker image for the project using `docker build -t image-tag .` and the image gets built successfully and when I run the image I am getting the below exception related to AWS authentication, I believe it requires the *.aws* folder with valid details but I am not sure how I can do that with docker.

**Error creating bean with name 'amazonS3' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/config/S3Configuration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3]: Factory method 'amazonS3' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.**

---

**application.properties**

```
# AWS Configurations
cloud.aws.end-point.uri = https://sqs.zone.amazonaws.com/id/name
cloud.aws.credentials.use-default-aws-credentials-chain = true
```

---

**S3Configuration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class S3Configuration {

  @Bean
  public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
  }
}
```

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY pom.xml /app/
COPY src /app/src
RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar /app/application.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/application.jar"]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I don't see aws credentials configured inside docker container. If you are looking to read it from .aws folder it should be there inside the docker container.

While you can do aws configure by installing cli with in your Dockerfile, I think it is better to read from environment variables with in your application. Then you just simply set the variables in Dockerfile:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = xxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = xxxx
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = xxx
```